# Regex expression to allow # only in between chars in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a JavaScript regex to handle

case 1. allow all chars, but '#' in between characters only

case 2. allow only alphanumeric and '#', but '#' in between chars

```
For example :
case1 : var formattedText = inputText.replace(/^(.+#+.)$/g, ''); //not working
```

Comment: `inputText.replace(/^#+|#+$/g,'')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all chars except # at the start and end, you might use a negated character class `[^#\r\n]` excluding `#` *(or newlines if desired)*

```
^[^#\r\n]+(?:#+[^#\r\n]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwG2bE/1)

To match only alphanumeric and # not at the start or end of the string, you might use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:#+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ6tMJ/1)

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:#+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/;
[
  "#test",
  "test#",
  "test",
  "test#test",
  "test#test#test"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, thank you for the answer. One query, what if I don’t want to validate the '#' at the end of the string?

Comment: @Soojoo Dp you mean that is should be allowed at the end?

Comment: @Soojoo Then you might use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[#a-zA-Z0-9]+$` https://regex101.com/r/qleCMH/1

Comment: Okay, got it, What about the case:1 then?

Comment: @Soojoo For case 1 you could use `^[^#\r\n]+.*$` https://regex101.com/r/bCRhgg/1 If for case 2 you also want to allow a single char `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[#a-zA-Z0-9]*$` https://regex101.com/r/RWsdIq/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226939/discussion-between-soojoo-and-the-fourth-bird).